# Disconnecting laptop keyboard and connecting external keyboard: viable solution?

Tags: keyboard, laptop-repair

My Sony vaio keyboard has started behaving erratically. It presses some random keys, other keys dont work.

Day 1: Numberpad Minus not working

Day 2: I, O, G, Home keys not working.

When I start up linux, the whole screen starts filling with ^[[D, ^[[G.

What is the problem? Will disconnecting the laptop keyboard and connecting a USB keyboard work? Or is the motherboard gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, test your keyboard also in BIOS setup, before booting to any OS. This way you can confirm there's nothing else what is causing the problem.

**Second**, most laptop keyboards have just a single connector to motherboard. You can try unplugging it and test whether you can still use the laptop (with external keyboard only).

Isn't your laptop still covered by warranty period? If it is, just make brief check based on the first pargraph above and then contact your vendor.

Comment: Thanks, I believe a BIOS test should expose the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most OS's support multiple input devices, so connecting an external keyboard is not likely to fix it.  If you can somehow disable the built in keyboard device it would probably resolve it though.